# how to return every second element in a java array

Tags: java

I am a new java lerner. I have a problem to understand how can I access in a for loop in Array.

```
public class ArrVers {
public static void main (String args []) {

}

public static int Annahme (int [] a) {

    int platzhalter [] = {1,3,4,5,6};

    for(int i = 0; i<platzhalter.length; i++) {

        return platzhalter [i+2];

    }
    return 0;

    }

}
```

I want to return every second Element of this array. Example {0,2,4,6,8} Here i want to print 0,4,8 on screen with "[".

Sorry for my bad English!
This is my code so far. I know im a noob yet, but i want to improve my skills and learn more.

Comment: that is not every second element . I feel that it's you want to print a value which is on even index?

Comment: Yes, i also want to return the index. Can i edit my for loop with i+2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        int platzhalter [] = {0,2,4,6,8};
        for (int i=0;i<platzhalter.length;i=i+2){
            System.out.print(platzhalter[i]);
        }
    }
```